# Rails: Validation for a simple_form using has_many relationship (e.g. Person, Phone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes, simple-form

I'm struggling getting the desired validation with nested models within a `simple_form`.  You'll be able to see from the models below a `Person` can have many `Phone`'s, the desired behaviour is to present edit fields for any existing numbers plus an additional one should for a new number, if this new number isn't filled in by the user then it's just ignore and not saved in the database. I also want to achieve similar with `Email`.

When landing on the /people/:id/edit page this blank field is being prematurely validated and producing visible errors on the form before submitting. It doesn't do this when visiting /people/:id/new page; I'm assuming that this is because `new_record?` returns true for the user model on the new page? In reading a similar post I added `on: :save` as a parameter to `validates` on the `Phone` model although this just allowed blank records into the database, perhaps because this isn't relevant when the user model is saving the record?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable
  has_many :emails, :as => :emailable
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable
  attr_accessible :first_name, :job_title, :last_name, :prefix, :phones_attributes, :emails_attributes, :addresses_attributes, :company_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['number'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['email'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

  def to_s
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end


class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phoneable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessible :number, :phone_type
  validates :number, :phone_type, presence: true, on: :save  # as suggested in a similar post, just allows blank records into database.
  def to_s
    "#{phone_type}: #{number}"
  end
end
```

With both the new and edit controller I'm creating a new instance of each of these models so that they show up on the form. `@person` is loaded in the controller using `load_and_authorize_resource` as part of cancan.

```
def new
  @person.phones << Phone.new
  @person.emails << Email.new
end
```

Here is the partial view for the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset id="<%= controller.action_name.capitalize %>_person">
    <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> Person</legend>

    <%= f.input :prefix %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.input :job_title %>
    <%= f.association :company, :prompt => "Select associated company..."  %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :phones do |phone| %>
      <%= phone.input :phone_type, :collection => %w(Work Home Mobile Fax Other), :default => "Work" %>
      <%= phone.input :number %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :emails do |email| %>
      <%= email.input :email_type, :collection => %w(Work Home Other), :default => "Work" %>
      <%= email.input :email %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  people_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>    
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Many thanks for any help in advance :-)

Comment: Wondering if I should be doing something like `@person.phones.build` rather than creating a instance with `Phone.new`.

Comment: Because it is a polymorphic association I would suggest that yes you use `@person.phones.build` what's these errors you are speaking about on the edit page?  Remember, using build is a form of tying that object to its predecessor. `@person.phones.build` tells the association that `@person` owns this, create object to `person_id`.